# Remove Leftover Thunderbird Notification Popup from Screen (Windows 8 Os)

Tags: operating-systems

I hope this question is within the scope of this stack exchange community. Thunderbird has a popup notification for new mail(see image), and for some reason, it got stuck in my screen. I was wondering if there is any way to remove it from the screen without having to restart my system. This is nothing serious, but I am just really curious.

OS: Windows 8.

P.S. Tried restarting the explorer, didn't work.

[image: Thunderbird Leftover Notification.]

Thank You.

Comment: This is not even remotely in scope.

Comment: On every Stack Exchange, there's a "help" link in the top-right corner.  Go to "Help center" and then "What topics can I ask about here" and then you don't need to hope that your question is on-topic.

Comment: Does it remain after closing all running applications? How about logging out and then back into Windows?

Comment: Try changing the screen resolution to something else and back.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I end up ending the thunderbird.exe process from the task manager. It is a bit niggly but I have not found a solution to the actual issue. I believe it has something to do with when the computer goes to sleep with Thunderbird running in the background.